# How to parse this long to int using typecasting

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I want to parse this to `int` using typecasting

```
int noOfTest = catDoc.getLong("NO_OF_TESTS").intValue();
```

How can I do it?

Comment: use this `Integer.parseInt(catDoc.getLong("NO_OF_TESTS").intValue());`

Comment: Have you solved the issue?